# It is possible to turn off page prefetching and caching in the Next.js SSG?

Tags: next.js

Even after the server goes down, I want to prevent the layout from showing up when I click on a link to another page.

Comment: you can set `prefetch=false` in your link?

Comment: Thank you very much. Prefetch could have been prevented that way. However.
If it was cached, the symptoms remained the same: if I clicked on a link to a page I had accessed in the past, even if the server was down, I was taken to that page and the layout was displayed.